# browseForOpenMultiple - crashing

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I am trying to work with browseForOpenMultiple function inside Flex, sdk 3.5, I am trying to figure out a bug. The browseForOpenMultiple does not crash everytime, but it seems as though I can upload a file once, but when I go to upload a second file, it crashes when the browseForOpenMultiple function is called. Anyone have any ideas about possible causes?

**Update:**

```
private function browseForFiles():void 
{ 
  fileBrowser = new File(); 
  fileBrowser.addEventListener(FileListEvent.SELECT_MULTIPLE, filesSelected); 
  fileBrowser.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, fileSelectionCancelled); 
  fileBrowser.browseForOpenMultiple("Select Desired Media File(s)", [(mode == "Media")? MediaTypes.getFileFilter() : MediaTypes.getVideoFilter()]); 
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that's crashing?

Comment: private function browseForFiles():void
   {
    fileBrowser = new File();
    fileBrowser.addEventListener(FileListEvent.SELECT_MULTIPLE, filesSelected);
    fileBrowser.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, fileSelectionCancelled);
    fileBrowser.browseForOpenMultiple("Select Desired Media File(s)", 
     [(mode == "Media")? MediaTypes.getFileFilter() : MediaTypes.getVideoFilter()]);
   }

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I put in some code that is around the error. I am testing inside of Flash Builder, and it does not go to the debugger, so no stack trace is given back. It just crashes and says "The application adl quit unexpectedly. Mac OSX and other applications are not affected. blah blah"

Comment: one other item, I threw a breakpoint at the end of my code. It went past the MediaTypes line, went back to the line of MXML that launched the browser, then the adl window starts bouncing, and it moves to the line of WindowedApplication for nativeWindow_deactivateHandler, like that gets triggered after the button action is complete. Then the crash window comes up.

Comment: @tcoulson Can you copy and paste the error message(s) that are in the crash window here?

Comment: is there a limit on the number of file types that FileFilter can take? I seem to be running into a limit, is it 50 or 60 file types?

Comment: @tcoulson I believe the list of file extensions is stored as a string, so I'd be surprised if you were hitting some kind of limit.

Comment: @Jason Towne - that is what the problem was, there were a lot of duplicates in the code I was checking, so I removed them, and the code no longer crashes the application. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

So the code in our array of file extensions was crashing when there were over 60 items listed in an array that gets converted into a string for the FileFilter. This may not be an Adobe limit, but I wanted to make mention that the crash is fixed, so that others who may be encountering issues with browseForOpenMultiple will know what the issue was for this problem. This is not code that I originally wrote, so I will check into it for more clues, but for the time being, too many array items being joined together into a string for FileFilter object caused the crash.

Answer (score 0):

It could be how it's construct the File, without a real file reference.

Try something like this :

```
var fileBrowser = File.desktopDirectory
```